# Port Android Application website? (edit: To any other platform?)

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, android-emulator

Is there anyway to port an Android application to a website?

EDIT: or port it to *any other platform*

For example, if people do not have Android (iOS, Computer, etc), I would like them to navigate to a website and access a web-version of the Android application.

Is this possible?

Comment: from what i know (could be wrong).  There isnt a straight converter.  But you could do a java applet.  Some of the code can be copy and pasted however stuff like activities and such are android specific

Comment: I think this video is worth watching [Google I/O 2011: HTML5 versus Android: Apps or Web for Mobile Development?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f2Zky_YyyQ).

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative is probably to do the opposite: start developing with an API that already provides support for HTML and Android applications.

Something like PhoneGap comes to mind.

---

> But is there a tool that ports an already-made Android app to any other platform?

None that I'm aware of. While you can encapsulate HTML apps inside the Android web components, you'd need to rewrite an entire compatibility layer to translate all the Android APIs to their equivalent HTML/Javascript... of course, I'm not even considering the feasibility of such project, considering the differences between each.

> EDIT: or port it to any other platform

Sorry for not addressing your question fully, I didn't notice that. Yes, like  Chris Stratton said, RIM were allowing Android apps to run on its Playbook tablets. Still, for HTML, to achieve great interoperability like you first asked, I'm not aware of any that would perform such task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

But is there a tool that ports an already-made Android app to _any_ other platform?

Comment: @DavidZhu RIM has such a tool for porting (or perhaps one should say repackaging?) Android apps to recent Blackberries, apparently it works to a degree but has some notable limitiations.  Last time I heard that included no support of native code.

Comment: True, they were even giving away Playbooks some time ago for Android devs willing to port their apps. Didn't notice that the OP changed the focus of his question.